# Varnish how to cache on public cache-control header

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I just started updating my VCL and found a good boilerplate on the web:
https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-5.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl

The only problem i have is that when i have a valid response header like `Cache-Control:public, max-age=2592000` it is not being cached and it keeps returning me a `MISS` all the time. I found out that if i return `unset beresp.http.set-cookie;` in below method all the time it will work but ofcourse it probably will cover way too much.

What is the correct way in setting this config so that it only caches at the point where the HTTP header tells it to do so?

```
# Handle the HTTP response coming from our backend
sub vcl_backend_response {
  # Called after the response headers has been successfully retrieved from the backend.

  # Pause ESI request and remove Surrogate-Control header
  if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
    unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
    set beresp.do_esi = true;
  }

  # Enable cache for all static files
  # The same argument as the static caches from above: monitor your cache size, if you get data nuked out of it, consider giving up the static file cache.
  # Before you blindly enable this, have a read here: https://ma.ttias.be/stop-caching-static-files/
  if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|otf|ogg|ogm|opus|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }

  # Large static files are delivered directly to the end-user without
  # waiting for Varnish to fully read the file first.
  # Varnish 4 fully supports Streaming, so use streaming here to avoid locking.
  if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bz2|flac|flv|gz|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|ogm|opus|rar|tar|tgz|tbz|txz|wav|webm|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.do_stream = true;  # Check memory usage it'll grow in fetch_chunksize blocks (128k by default) if the backend doesn't send a Content-Length header, so only enable it for big objects
  }

  # Sometimes, a 301 or 302 redirect formed via Apache's mod_rewrite can mess with the HTTP port that is being passed along.
  # This often happens with simple rewrite rules in a scenario where Varnish runs on :80 and Apache on :8080 on the same box.
  # A redirect can then often redirect the end-user to a URL on :8080, where it should be :80.
  # This may need finetuning on your setup.
  #
  # To prevent accidental replace, we only filter the 301/302 redirects for now.
  if (beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
    set beresp.http.Location = regsub(beresp.http.Location, ":[0-9]+", "");
  }

  # Set 2min cache if unset for static files
  if (beresp.ttl <= 0s || beresp.http.Set-Cookie || beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
    set beresp.ttl = 120s; # Important, you shouldn't rely on this, SET YOUR HEADERS in the backend
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
  }

  # Don't cache 50x responses
  if (beresp.status == 500 || beresp.status == 502 || beresp.status == 503 || beresp.status == 504) {
    return (abandon);
  }

  # Allow stale content, in case the backend goes down.
  # make Varnish keep all objects for 6 hours beyond their TTL
  set beresp.grace = 6h;

  return (deliver);
}
```